# How do I read from file using pebble c?

Tags: c, file-io, pebble-watch, cloudpebble

I have tried using a function that would work in "regular" c:

```
const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
        tok && *tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
    if (!--num)
        return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* stream = fopen("v1.csv", "r");

    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stdin))
    {
        char* tmp = strdup(line);
        printf("Field 3 would be %s\n", getfield(tmp, 3));
        // NOTE strtok clobbers tmp
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

I am trying to read a file names "v1.csv" located in my pebble app resources folder.

Comment: And what is your problem? I tried your code, it seems to me, that work, but next time it would be good if you post your input file (v1.csv). for me it is not clear where do you want read, stdin or stream? Did you mean: 'while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))' ?

Comment: hmm, for me, cloud pebble highlights `FILE* stream = fopen("v1.csv", "r");` and the while loop as errors. It won't compile. As for `v1.csv`, it is far too large to post, but this should work for all cdv files i presume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not read/write to files, use file descriptor or any of the `f*` functions in the Pebble SDK.

If you want to store data on the watch, you should look into the [Persistent Storage API](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/pebble-apps/app-structure/persistent-storage/).